# Display more nodes in decision tree in R?

Tags: r, decision-tree

Base on the result I have 7 nodes, I wanted to have more than 2 nodes displayed in the result, but existing it seemed that I keep on having 2 nodes displayed.

Is there a way to display more nodes and in a nicer way?

```
 library(rpart)

 tr1<-rpart(leaveyrx~marstx.f+age+jobtitlex.f+organizationunitx.f+fteworkschedule+nationalityx.f+eesubgroupx.f+lvlx.f+sttpmx.f+ staff2ndtpmx.f+staff3rdtpmx.f+staff4thtpmx.f, method="class",data=btree) 

 printcp(tr1)

 plotcp(tr1) 

 summary(tr1)

 plot(tr1, uniform=TRUE, margin = 0.2, main="Classification Tree for Exploration") text(tr1, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.5)
```

*A repost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably is not your plot, but rather your decision tree model. Can you clarify why you expect 7 nodes? When you only have two (leaf) nodes, it probably means that your model is only using one predictor variable and using a binary classification as the response variable. This is probably caused by the predictor variable having a 1:1 relation with the response variable. For example, if you are predicting Gender (Male, Female) and one of your response variables is Sex (M,F). In this case, a decision tree model is not needed because you can just use the predictor variable. Maybe something happened in the pre-processing of your data that copied the response variable. Here are a few things to look for:

1) Calculate the Correct Classification Rate (CCR). If it is 0, then you have a perfect model.

```
yhat<-predict(tr1, type="class") # Model Predictions
sum(yhat != btree$leaveyrx)/nrow(btree) # CCR
```

2) See which predictor your model is using. Double check that this variable has been processed correctly. Try excluding it from the model.

```
tr1$variable.importance
```

3) If you are absolutely sure the variable is calculated correctly and that it should be used in the model, try increasing your cp value. The default is 0.01. But decision trees will run quickly even with high cp values. While you are tinkering with the cp values, also consider the other tuning parameters. ?rpart.control

```
control <- rpart.control(minbucket = 20, cp = 0.0002, maxsurrogate = 0, usesurrogate = 0, xval = 10)
tr1 <- rpart(leaveyrx~marstx.f+age+jobtitlex.f+organizationunitx.f+fteworkschedule+nationalityx.f+eesubgroupx.f+lvlx.f+sttpmx.f+ staff2ndtpmx.f+staff3rdtpmx.f+staff4thtpmx.f,
             data=btree,
             method = "class",
             control = control)
```

4) Once you have a tree with many nodes, you will need to trim it back. It may that your best model is really only driven off of one variable and hence will only have two nodes

```
# Plot the cp
plotcp(tr1)
printcp(tr1) # Printing cp table (choose the cp with the smallest xerror)

# Prune back to optimal size, according to plot of CV r^2
tr1.pruned <- prune(tr1, cp=0.001)  #approximately the cp corresponding to the best size
```

5) the rpart libary is a good resource for plotting the decision trees. There are are lots of great articles out there, but here is one a good one on rpart: http://www.milbo.org/rpart-plot/prp.pdf

It may also be helpful to post a bit of the summary of your model.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I am unsure the summary you are referring to the info below ;  Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] age      sttpmx.f
Root node error: 32/94 = 0.34043
n= 94 
CP nsplit rel error  xerror    xstd
1 0.21875      0   1.00000 1.00000 0.14357
2 0.06250      1   0.78125 0.87500 0.13856
3 0.01000      2   0.71875 0.84375 0.13709

Comment: Sorry, i need to do 2 posts as limited by the no. of characters.            
                                                                                                   ///   
                                                                                           
 Variable importance
  sttpmx.f staff2ndtpmx.f  age  staff3rdtpmx.f staff4thtpmx.f 
     36             27             18             11              2 
nationalityx.f  eesubgroupx.f       marstx.f 
           2              2              2

Comment: Hmm, it is difficult to read the values in your comment because of the formatting. But it looks like you CP = 1. Can you confirm? By summary, I mean the output of summary(tr1). Consider editing your post instead of pasting this in the comments for better visability.

Comment: Hi@Jeffrey, refers to  Correct Classification Rate (CCR) script, do we use it on the test data? I obtained a zero when use on btree, but with a warning "In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'" Secondly, there is no value for the CP. Outcome : 1st root split between 0 and 1-> 2nd level node split betw 0 and 0-> 3rd level node :split betw 0 & 0 ->4th level split 0&1. (I add in more variables). Have you encountered this kind of outcome before? It looks strange to me that there are splitting on 0 instead of 0 & 1.

Comment: Normally, you would want to to use your test dataset to validate your model and calculate your CCR. However, decision trees are great because rpart library automatically cross-validates your train data... so you are safe to validate your model on your train data. Anyways, it is strange that you model is splitting at zero. My suspicion is that you have faulty data - your model only really likes 1 variable and you have forced additional splits. 

If my answer solved your issues, please mark it as solved. Otherwise, please clarify why you believe your model should have more than 1 split/nodes.

Comment: Hi@Jeffrey, thank you very much for your guidance. Managed to resolve it. The suspected cause was due to lack of data. I will mark this question solved.